# Cannot build Cordova for Visual Studio with PushPlugin installed

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015

I recently installed VS2015 with Cordova tools.
I am trying to create a simple app that will receive push notifications.
To reproduce my issue:

1. New Project -> Blank Apache Cordova app
2. Double click config.xml to get the configuration ui
3. Add the "PushPlugin" plugin by going to Plugins -> Custom -> Git -> https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin
4. Try to build the app

I get the following error:

```
1>  Installing "com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin" for android
1>  Running command: E:\Code\AnotherCordovaTest\AnotherCordovaTest\platforms\android\cordova\version.bat
1>  Command finished with error code 0: E:\Code\AnotherCordovaTest\AnotherCordovaTest\platforms\android\cordova\version.bat
1>  Install start for "com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin" on android.
1>  Beginning processing of action stack for android project...
1>  Parsing android project files...
1>  Installing Android library: com.android.support:support-v4:+
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I am uncertain what exactly is wrong here, or how to fix it. I can't seem to get anymore detailed error messages.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem with the 2.5.0 version of the PushPlugin.

But it build fine with the [2.4.0 version](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/releases/tag/2.4.0).

Download the zip and retrieve the plugin from the unzip local folder.